# Connect and disconnect data card using node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I want to do a task with node js console application which follows the following algorithm:

- Connect datacard via code (Get a new static IP)
- Do some operations via that IP
- On call back of the above operation disconnnect the data card
- Loop back to step 1

Is there any way I can accomplish this via Node.js?? 
I've found the [solutions for C/C++ and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056784/how-to-detect-datacard-connect-and-disconnect-event-on-win32) but not for node js.. Can anyone please help??

Comment: what do you mean by datacard ?

Comment: Data card is the internet dongle which you use to access wireless internet ..  Vodafone, Airtel, Virgin and  Docomo are all ISPs and are data card providers

Comment: I am talking about a thing like this http://www.amazon.in/Modem-ZTE-DATA-MF197-Speed/dp/B00LHQW9W8?tag=googinhydr18418-21&kpid=B00LHQW9W8&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=3f8b408e-7d57-3e89-bba4-00006bd1d8aa

Comment: So you basically want node to perform some OS related commands (connected / disconnecting the card) did you check node's C/C++ addons Documentation ?

Comment: Yes, i want to do this only. I havent checked any documentation of C/C++ addons

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the [wireless](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wireless) module, a utility for handling interactions with wireless interfaces on *nix distributions. The module is still in development but the functions you need (connect/disconnet) are already working. There is a dependency on the wpa_supplicant tool being installed, so the PC node.js is running needs to have it installed to allow this module to work.

wpa_supplicant is the IEEE 802.1X/WPA component that is used in the client stations. It implements key negotiation with a WPA authenticator and it controls the roaming and IEEE 802.11 authentication/association of the wireless driver.

Here's an example of enabling an interface, taken from the module's page:

```
var wireless = new Wireless({
    iface: 'wlan0',
    updateFrequency: 10, // Optional, seconds to scan for networks 
    connectionSpyFrequency: 2, // Optional, seconds to scan if connected 
    vanishThreshold: 2 // Optional, how many scans before network considered gone 
});

wireless.enable(function(err) {
    wireless.start();
});
```

Comment: Where do I set the Dialler number? APN and other settings??

Comment: And I am not able to connect via this piece of code.. I think I need to supply more information like dialing number and network APN.